# How to run a batch file over a period of time repeatedly : Scheduling a task

Tags: windows, batch-file, scheduled-tasks

I've a task(.bat file) which should be performed/executed after every 15mins.

I don't know where to make its entry so that it'll be scheduled?

With this, I want to see the execution(progress) of the task running(in command prompt).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

take a look at `schtasks` command to set task on the command line

```
C:\test>schtasks /?
```

Comment: + 1 `schtasks` is superior to `at` in most cases, but be aware that it is not available in Windows XP Home or any version prior to XP.

Comment: How can I see the progress of my .bat file

Comment: don't understand. Elaborate. Also, edit your original question to include this question, clearly elaborated

Comment: I did. I just want to see the execution of the running task.

Answer (score 1):

The **[Task Scheduler](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/178706)** is an easy way to do this manually.

If you need to script it, look at the **[`at`](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/commandlinereference/p/at-command.htm)** command.

Answer (score 0):

Quoted from a Microsoft Technet article, [Schtasks](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725744%28WS.10%29.aspx):

```
; To schedule a task that runs every 20 minutes
;
; The following command schedules a security script, Sec.vbs,
; to run every 20 minutes. The ; command uses the /sc parameter
; to specify a minute schedule and the /mo parameter to specify
; an interval of 20 minutes.

; Because the command does not include a starting date or time,
; the task starts 20 minutes after the command completes, and
; runs every 20 minutes thereafter whenever the system is running.
; Notice that the security script source file is located on a
; remote computer, but that the task is scheduled and executes
; on the local computer.

schtasks /create /sc minute /mo 20 /tn "Security Script" /tr \\central\data\scripts\sec.vbs
```

You can find more explanations and examples in the reference mentioned above.