# need a script to run Selenium IDE Browser Automation every 15 min

Tags: selenium

Hi all i asked a question a few minutes ago without thinking so here is more detail of what i need to do

I have to complete a webpage every 15 min and record the result

I have setup Selenium IDE to complete the webpage for me but i have to manually run its script every 15 min

What would be the easiest way to automate it so i can set a script running in the morning and it would then run Selenium IDE every 15 min, then record the output to a spreadsheet

Also i would need to be notified if the webpage didn't return a result or Selenium failed

I have looked around on google etc but cant find a straight answer

can some please point me in the right direction ?

Answer (score 3):

My suggestion would be to not run it using IDE. I don't think it's possible without some other automation tool.

I'd suggest doing this:

1. Create a WebDriver (or RC if you wish) test using your preferred language.
2. If using linux, just use `crontab` to set up a 15 minute cronjob. If using windows, use task scheduler to run your test.

Comment: I have not got a preferred language this is all new new to me can you please assist ?

Comment: Eek.. well of course any language that you prefer, works. I prefer to use either java when using selenium, but to each his own. If you're looking for a java framework, you can download http://github.com/ddavison/getting-started-with-selenium  - that's the framework I use for any automation using selenium

Comment: can you point me in a direction of any instructions n how to achive this?, sorry i am a novice wen it comes to this

Answer (score 0):

Your root problem is "how do I schedule a task to run repeatedly" without Selenium needing to be part of the equation.  I'm going to guess you are on Windows in which case refer to [How to run a batch file over a period of time repeatedly : Scheduling a task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3958896/how-to-run-a-batch-file-over-a-period-of-time-repeatedly-scheduling-a-task)

Comment: Unfortunately, windows scheduled tasks run in the background and no longer have access to the foreground windows session.  So, you wont be able to run a Selenium test using that method.  It will work with Windows XP though.

Answer (score 0):

The other two answers on this thread have the flaw that the Selenium WebDriver will need to use the foreground X-session to run the browser within.   So, you need to run a scheduler in the foreground.    What you can do to test it, is to install a [Jenkins server](http://jenkins-ci.org/) on your system and make sure you execute it in a foreground shell (not a background shell script).  Then, create a jenkins job that executes your selenium test and it should be able to access the foreground X (or windows) session.

You can run Selenium in a backgrounded session only if you use PhantomJS, HtmlUnit, [Apache HttpComponents](http://hc.apache.org/), or "headless Chrome".   To do that is more of a technical answer not covered here.